# Checking Online Status PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying to figure this out.  I have the `login_handler` sending the current time to the db in `users` - `last_login`.  What I want to do now is subtract this from the current time and set the user status to either online or offline. I have the following:

```
global $con;

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($datarows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $datarows['username'];
    $db_last = $datarows['last_login'];
    $current = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //Current date/time

    $difference = strtotime($current) - strtotime($db_last);
    $diff_in_mins = $difference/60;

    if($diff_in_mins < 4){
     $updateStatus = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET status='online'");
    } else {
     $updateStatus = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET status='offline'");
    }
 ?>

 <table>
     <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $diff_in_mins; ?></td>
 </table>

 <?php } ?>
```

When I log in as a certain user, that users `last_login` changes (& only that user) to the current `timestamp` and the echo `$diff_in_mins` indicates that.  However when I refresh the page for the above code (this is not functional, still trying to figure it out) all of the last_login fields become the same...?  Everyone gets set to online & pretty much falls apart.

Can anyone shed some light on this, any help would be appreciated?

Thankyou, 
ep

UPDATE:
I need this to update dynamically, so when a user profile is accessed by another user they can tell if that person is online or not.  I decided to write it as a function of User class and now have the following:

```
public function getStatus() {
    $username = $this->user['username'];
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT last_login FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    return $row['last_login'] = $db_last;
    $current = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //Current date/time
    $difference = strtotime($current) - strtotime($db_last);

    $diff_in_mins = ($difference / 60);

        if($diff_in_mins < 5){
            $updateStatus = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE users SET status='online' WHERE username='$username'");
        } else {
            $updateStatus = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE users SET status='offline' WHERE username='$username'");
        }

    $query_status = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT status FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $status_row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_status);
    return $status_row['status'];
}
```

The problem I'm getting now is: Undefined variable: db_last.  I think...the above logic is sound, but I must have a syntax error...?  Any help is appreciated!  :)

Comment: well first off there should probably be a `WHERE username = $name` or something along those lines in your `updateStatus` query.  You're currently just updating every record on every iteration

Comment: you `select * from users`, that's why you updated all accounts.

Comment: I was trying to update every iteration, with only those recently logged in being set to online.  Shouldn't the $diff_in_mins variable capture that data for each?  The idea is someone would log in and this would scan the db to check whose online.  Is it better to just update that variable for each indiv. user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the culprit:

```
return $row['last_login'] = $db_last;
```

changed to:

```
$db_last = $row['last_login'];
```

Works great now.  Thought I would post the answer for anyone who might come across a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your update query and try it.

```
    "UPDATE users SET status='online' WHERE 
    username=$name"
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @KakashiHatake.  I'm updated my question; if you can see anything there you may be able to help on that would be appreciated.  :)